# How to pass value from Dashing's .erb to the job (.rb)

Tags: ruby, dashing

I want to use a widget twice on my Dashing dashboard, but with different options. I'd like to set those options in the html like so:

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
    <div data-id="myweather" data-view="myweather" data-offset="0">
</li>
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
    <div data-id="myweather" data-view="myweather" data-offset="1">
</li>
```

The theory being I can have both Now and In-One-Hour weather widgets, but I can't workout how to get the `offset` value in the job file so that I can use it for fetching the data.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer since I do not have 50 points to just comment.

I don't believe this is possible. The way dashing works is that all communication goes from the server, a.k.a. jobs, to the web client. Notice how the jobs are started even before you load one page, so they do not know what channels are currently displayed. You can create multiple channels (myweather-offset-0, myweather-offset-1, etc) and send_event to all of them.

Comment: ... and by not possible, I mean within the confines of dashing. You can have the .erb do an ajax call and save some data which the job checks. Or something similarly ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But, I am not sure how you are planning to use.

You would have to modify the .html file of the corresponding widget to pass values.

For example, in my 'list' widget's .html I can do (added second tag)

```
<h1 class="title" data-bind="title"></h1>
<h1 class="title" data-bind="myown"></h1>
```

In my .erb I can bind myown like this (at the end).

```
 <div data-id="buzzwords" data-view="List" data-unordered="true" data-title="Buzzwords" data-moreinfo="# of times said around the office" data-myown="some random string"></div>
```

Comment: But the html file doesn't pass data to the job.